# Android Wearable.DataApi: reliable data storage?

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Background: I have an app which runs on an Android handheld (phone) but whose main purpose is to interact with an Android Wear watch. Correspondingly, the main source of data in the app is the wearable (not the handheld). I'm not currently using the DataApi to send this data from the wearable to the handheld; I had some issues with its reliability in the early days of Android Wear, so I rolled my own using the MessageApi.

Separately, I also cache the data I receive from the wearable in a SQLite database (on the handheld), so that my app has something to work with when the devices aren't connected.

Both of these pieces are working OK, but involve quite a bit of code. My question is, could the DataApi replace both my messaging layer **and** my local cache?

Obviously, the answer to the first half should be *yes*. This is what the DataApi is for, and in testing recently, it seems to have stabilized considerably since I first tried it out.

The second half is much less obvious. On paper, it looks like it could; the DataApi includes methods like `getDataItem()` which, apparently, can be used to retrieve data items which were synced previously. But this isn't its main function - is this aspect reliable enough to, well, *rely* upon for my app's main data storage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `DataApi` actually uses `sqlite` to persist data on both devices. You are duplicating efforts, if you are using `MessageApi` and your own persistence.

Answer (score 0):

i do not suggest using data api for data cache, because
1. data api queue cache has space limit, last time my test result is about 10MB
2. data api can not detect each data item if you put the same data content
3. data api may be deleted after use the item.